# PyQt - Detect which item has been changed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Is it possible to detect which particular item (row would be sufficient) has been changed?

The point is that I have to change the database after the item has been changed in a QtTableWidget.

My solution: I refill whole database table everytime I detect itemChanged signal. This way is very unefficient if the table has many rows. I want to detect a row which has been changed and update only that row in a database.

Answer (score 2):

The itemChanged signal should also pass the item that was changed in the callback function. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#itemChanged

```
def changed(item):
    row = item.row()
    column = item.column()
```